# Twilio TwilioRestClient 'SendMessage' method does not detect compiler error in c#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, twilio, sendmessage

I have installed twilio api in my c# project and import library. Now I want to send sms from WF Application. I used this format(https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), but TwilioRestClient 'SendMessage' method does not detect. I get compiler error.
-Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
-I have installed all Twilio packages from Nutget. Twilio,Twilio.Mvc,Twilio.Twiml

[My visual studio view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgq8W.png)

Comment: am add twilio, twilio.Mvc,twilio,Twiml referances

Comment: Can you expand on "does not detect"?  Are you getting a compiler error?  If you can you post that error?

Comment: Yes compailer error

Comment: Can you post the compiler error?  Can you also post what version of Visual Studio you're using and what version of .NET you are targeting?  Finally, can you also make sure that when you install the nuget package that you're choosing to install the highest version of its dependencies.  You should see version 105.X.X of RestSharp installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code.  Its available at this link
https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp
Its working fine in VS2015 update3

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Clients;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SendSms().Wait();
      Console.Write("Press any key to continue.");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task SendSms()
    {
      var accountSid = "ACba92b39902bc361138fea39fee0a41b7"; // Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
      var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}";   // Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console

      TwilioClient.init(accountSid, authToken);
      var restClient = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);

      var message = await
        new MessageCreator(
          new PhoneNumber("+12345678901"),  // To number
          accountSid,
          "Hello from C#"
        ).CreateAsync(restClient);

      Console.WriteLine(message.GetSid());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall existing `Twilio` and install 4.7.2 using the following commands in package manger console. Run one after another:

`uninstall-package twilio`
`Install-Package Twilio -Version 4.7.2`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of twilio did you install? The later version seem to lack this method. Try a lower version if on the latest. Worked for me.

Comment: account-verification-csharp-master  sample does not work with current NuGet!